# Как запретить повторный вывод одних и тегже постов?

Tags: django

У меня есть вот такой фильтр

```
Article.objects.filter(Q(connect_id=user_id) | Q(comment_article__user_id=user_id))
```

Но он выводит одну и туже запись несколько раз как это запретить делать?

Comment: может у тебя все таки несколько записей, удовлетворяющих условию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я нашел ответ [distinct()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

```
Article.objects.filter(Q(connect_id=user_id) | Q(comment_article__user_id=user_id)).distinct()
```